# Problem with Leaflet marker collision detection

Tags: leaflet, geojson

This code cannot detect marker collision. I am using a geojson file of points.

I used a javascript plugin for collision detection. Plugin source:
https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision

My Code is given below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Collision LayerGroup example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .city-label {
            background: white;
            border: 1px solid #888;

            position: relative;

            display: inline-block;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }



    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rbush@2.0.1/rbush.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.layergroup.collision@0.3.1/src/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision.js"></script>

    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([23.7303195, 90.4151661], 10);

        var layer = L.tileLayer('http://tile.openstreetmap.jp/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution:
                'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; ' +
                'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            useCache: true
        });

        layer.addTo(map);

        var collisionLayer = L.LayerGroup.collision({margin:5});

        var y = $.getJSON("dhanmondi.geojson",function(data){
                                      // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
                                        var countriesLayerNode = L.geoJson(
                                        data,{
                                        /*{
                                            style : countriesStyle,*/
                                            //for popup

                                            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                                           var marker =  L.marker(latlng);
                                                 return marker;
                                             }

                                        }
                                    );
                                collisionLayer.addLayer(countriesLayerNode);
                             });
                             collisionLayer.addTo(map);


        // It is also possible to init the markers at layer instantiation time.
//          new L.LayerGroup.collision(markers).addTo(map);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```